# Levelling in FIFA 12

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12 you are awarded XP and rise through experience levels. Are the experience levels actually used for anything, e.g. unlocking features? If so, is there a list somewhere of what gets unlocked at each level?

Comment: would be nice if leveling had an impact on the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points are used to compare yourself with other players, and the points you earn are also given to whatever club you've chosen (whether you are actively playing as that club or not), which are then used to rank the clubs in week long "seasons".

The levels themselves are just used as a comparison tool.

Comment: So the level itself has no purpose then?

Comment: Not as far as I could determine. Just a comparison tool.

Comment: Yep, I'm fairly certain there is no "bigger meaning" to the experience points, besides ego pushing and the _support your club_ ranking.